# WPF : how to add item in listview form textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem in `ListView`. I want to add some text in `ListView` from a textbox but here I can add 1 item why? What I'm trying to do is

- add text to a listview from a textbox
- Load text from `file.txt` (like split) and put it into the listview

When you press the button, it is added once.

Here is the text stored in file.txt

```
Ice Cream|22|Canned Goods|50|Meat & Seafood|80
```

I want to split the line from `file.txt` and put it into a listview

```
Ice Cream|22
```

`Ice Cream` will be in the first place and `22` it will be in second place

[image]

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="20,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280" Background="#FF636363" Foreground="White">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NameItem}" Width="210"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ItemFast}" Width="55"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Here is the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.IO;

namespace Wpf_ListView
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        StreamReader SR;
        StreamWriter SW;

        public List<DataItems> MyData { get; set; }

        ListBox LB = new ListBox();

        System.Timers.Timer TimerReader = new System.Timers.Timer();

        string[] ReadAllText;
        string LoadText;

        int x = 0;

        string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\File\Data.txt";

        private void MainWindow1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SR = new StreamReader(path);
            ReadAllText = SR.ReadToEnd().ToString().Split('|');
            SR.Close();

            foreach (var item in ReadAllText)
            {
                LB.Items.Add(item);
            }

            TimerReader.Elapsed += ReadTick;
            TimerReader.Interval = 100;
            TimerReader.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void ReadTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
           {
               try
               {
                   MyData = new List<DataItems>();
                   DataItems data = new DataItems();

                   data.NameItem = LB.Items[x].ToString();
                   x++;
                   data.ItemFast = LB.Items[x].ToString();
                   x++;

                   MyData.Add(data);
                   DataContext = this;

                   if (x == LB.Items.Count)
                   {
                       x = 0;
                       TimerReader.Enabled = false;
                   }
               }
               catch
               {

               }
           });
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyData = new List<DataItems>();

            DataItems data = new DataItems();
            data.NameItem = ItemNames.Text; // textbox 1
            data.ItemFast = ItemPrices.Text; // textbox 2

            MyData.Add(data);
            DataContext = this;

            SR = new StreamReader(path);
            LoadText = SR.ReadToEnd(); // Here because the new text has been placed and the old one will be deleted, so I called it up again before deleting it
            SR.Close();

            SW = new StreamWriter(path);
            SW.Write(LoadText + ItemNames.Text + "|" + ItemPrices.Text + "|");
            SW.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I created a class called `DataItems`:

```
namespace Wpf_ListView
{
    public class DataItems
    {
        public string NameItem { get; set; }
        public string ItemFast { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Load text from file.txt (like split)" - is this the part you are struggling with? Because I cannot see an attempt to split the text into individual items. Then I would suggest you concentrate your question on this part and leave all the WPF etc. stuff away.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i created timer for split and put it in list view (I don't know if this is the correct way to enter the data), I previously dealt with ListView in "Windows Forms" but is not work in wpf

Comment: thank you Jaek after 2 hour tried, finally its work. but why i cant put more then 1 item in the listView form button,

`DataItems data = new DataItems();`
`NameItem = TextBox1.Text;`
`data.NameItems = NameItem;`
`ItemFast = TextBox2.Text;`
`data.ItemPrices = ItemFast;`

`MyData.Add(data);`
`DataContext = this;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 2 problems here:

**First:** when you load your items from your *items.txt* file you don't loop on items.

In your *ReadTick* method:

```
MyData = new List<DataItems>();
DataItems data = new DataItems();

data.NameItem = LB.Items[x].ToString();
x++;
data.ItemFast = LB.Items[x].ToString();
x++;

MyData.Add(data);
```

You just add in your list the first item.
You should use a ***for*** loop to get all your items.
For example:

```
MyData = new List<DataItems>();
    
for (int x = 0; x < LB.Items.Count; x++) {
   DataItems data = new DataItems();
   NameItem = LB.Items[x].ToString();
   data.NameItem = NameItem;
   x++;
   ItemFast = LB.Items[x].ToString();
   data.ItemFast = ItemFast;
    
   MyData.Add(data);
}
```

and remove the second useless `x++`.

As you can see I add 2 new properties:

```
public string NameItem { get; set; }
public string ItemFast { get; set; }
```

And this is your **Second** problem: bindings.

Result:

[image]